# Prevent CKEditor add tags on OSX Safari when ctrl+V from MS Word

Tags: safari, ckeditor

There is a problem in ckeditor4. When I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> from MS Word on Windows, it removes all tags and in source view I can see that there are only `p` and `br` tags (and this is what I need), but when this pasting being performed on MacOSX in Safari, in CKEditor in source view I can see that there a lot of "garbage" was added — I mean `o` and `w` tags:

[image: Pasting on MacOSX, Safari]

Of course `forcePasteAsPlainText = true;`

And the question is how to prevent adding these tags?

Unfortunately this CMS will be used by client to which I can't say "Paste in notepad first.." or something like that :) Only <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using latest CKEditor 4.7.3.

I have seen your result in older CKEditors which had `pastefromword` plugin removed but the newest one seems to be working fine even with `ACF` disabled and `pastefromword` plugin removed.

The only way to get rid of these extra tags in older editor is to have `pastefromword` plugin available in your setup.

Comment: See some upvotes, so maybe it helped to others, but not in my case.
Tryed with latest 4.7.3
config.disallowedContent = 'xml,o,w';
config.removeFormatTags = 'xml,o,w,ins,kbd';
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;

Comment: Could you update your post and show your editor configuration?

Comment: Sure!
in config.js:
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
config.allowedContent = true;
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
config.disallowedContent = 'xml,o,w';
config.removeFormatTags = 'xml,o,w,ins,kbd';
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
};

Comment: First of all Please remove `config.disallowedContent = 'xml,o,w'; config.removeFormatTags = 'xml,o,w,ins,kbd'; ` because they do nothing. You can't disable ACF with `config.allowedContent = true;` and then change the way it works with `disallowedContent ` because it won't have any effect.

Comment: Second, you seem to be using some customized package which is neither `full` nor `standard` where pasting works without problems. Could try enabling ACF (please remove `config.allowedContent = true;`) and see if it is working with your custom package and if this won't work could you try using the `standard` package?

Comment: Worked.  Even if there is still 'span' and styles inside 'p' but at least without "garbage" on my screenshot above. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a report in CKEditor Bug tracker - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1013. I think that this is solved no more `spans` or `styles` will be there after pasting. At the moment I can only recommend using https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterPasteFromWord.

Comment: Here is an example which removes styled `spans` and `paragraphs`: `var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});editor.on( 'afterPasteFromWord', function( evt ){ var html = evt.data.dataValue;  html = html.replace( /<(p|span)\s+style="[a-zA-Z0-9&:;%,.\- ]*">/ig ,''); html = html.replace( /<\/(p|span)>/ig ,''); evt.data.dataValue = html;} );`